# Passenger 5 is listing public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, cpanel

I'm using Centos cPanel with Passenger, the app is working when I access in to the sections for example */home* or */login* but it displays the files when I access directly to the page */*.

This is my .htaccess config

```
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerLoadShellEnvVars On
PassengerAppRoot /home/claude/rails/claude
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/wrappers/ruby
RackEnv production
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
```

I already tried disabling autoindex

```
#LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

but it doesn't let me restart apache.

Does anyone have resolved this issue before?

Thanks.

Comment: I already tried with

` Options -Indexes` 

and got a 404 error and this log:

`AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/claude/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (none)`

Comment: Typically that would mean that the /public dir has chmod 777.

This might prove useful: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/

Comment: It has 775, already tried with 755 and 777, but the default was 775

Answer (score 0):

Done!

So the issue was that I installed first passenger-5.0.10 but for some reason Apache was trying to load passenger-5.0.30 but I was including the other version in httpd.conf so I reinstalled again passenger 5.0.30 and that was it.

Thanks.